# With $g(x) = f(1/x)$ for $0 > x > 1/a$, prove that $f$ has a limit at Negative Infinity if and only if $g$ has a limit at $0$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

> Define $$g(x) = f\left(\frac1x\right)$$ for $0 > x > 1/a$. Prove that $f$ has a limit at Negative Infinity if and only if $g$ has a limit at $0$.

Basically what the question asks. This formula is very similar to a previous proof I already did for class that asked for the limit at Positive Infinity. I've talked to my professor about this problem, and what he told me isn't really sticking.

Basically, $f$ is defined on $\{x : x < a\}$, but what he told me is that $a$ doesn't have to be a negative number. But we are focusing on negative infinity, so I didn't follow it. He also told me that "the definition of limit at infinity absolutely should not care what $f$ is doing on the negatives. So we can say, Without loss of Generality, assume $a > 0$."

But I need to explain why and I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Since you seem to have a two-sided limit for $g$, this is false as written.  Let $g(x) = 2^{-1/x} = f(1/x)$.  Then $g$ does not have a two-sided limit at $0$.  $g$ does have a limit as $x \rightarrow 0^-$ and the existence of **this** one-sided limit is equivalent to the existence of $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(1/x)$.  (Worth noticing: all limits at infinity are one-sided limits...)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think that you want to prove:
$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)$ exists $\Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}}f(\frac{1}{x})$ exists.
Also we have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}}f(\frac{1}{x})$.\

Proof:

We have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(-x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}}f(-x)$.
Here (sorry but I don`t know how cite. There is a post in that proved that)proved that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}f(\frac{1}{x})$.
By the previous properties we have that:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(-x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}f(\frac{1}{-x})=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}}f(\frac{1}{x})
$$